# how to calculate weighted average but exclude the object itself using SAS

Tags: sas

There are four variables in my dataset. `Company` shows the company's name. `Return` is the return of `Company` at day `Date`. `Weight` is the weight of this company in the market.

I want to keep all variables in the original file, and create an additional variable which is the market return (exclude `Company` itself). Market return corresponding for stock 'a' is the sum of all weighted stocks' return at the same `Date` in the market exclude stock a.  For example, if there are 3 stocks in the market a, b and c. Market Return for stock a is Return(b)* [Weight(b)/(weight(b)+weight(C))] + Return(C)* [weight(C)/(weight(b)+weight(C)]. Similarly, Market Return for stock b is Return(a)* [Weight(a)/(weight(a)+weight(C))] + Return(C)* [weight(C)/(weight(a)+weight(C)].

I try to use proc summary but this function cannot exclude stock a when calculate the market return for stock a.

```
PROC SUMMARY NWAY DATA  ; 
    CLASS Date ; 

    VAR Return / WEIGHT = weight;

    OUTPUT
       OUT = output
       MEAN (Return) = MarketReturn;
RUN;
```

Could anyone teach me how to solve this please. I am relatively new to this software, so I dont know if I should use loop or there might be some better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a bit of fancy algebra.  It's not something that's built-in, though.

Basically:

- Construct a "total" market return
- Construct a stock by stock return (so just return of A)
- Subtract out the portion that A contributes to total.

Thanks to the simple math that generates these lists, it's quite easy to do this.

> Total sum = ((mean of `A*Awgt`) + (mean of remainder*sum of their weights))/(sum of Awgt + sum of rest wgts)

So, solve that for (mean of rest*mean of rest wgts / sum of rest wgts).

> Exclusive sum: ((mean of all * sum of all wgts) - (mean of A * sum of A wgts)) / (sum of all wgts - sum of A wgts)

Something like this.

```
data returns;
  input stock $ return weight;
  datalines;
A .50 1
B .75 2
C .33 1
;;;;
run;

proc means data=returns;
  class stock;
  types () stock; *this is the default;
  weight weight;
  output out=means_out mean= sumwgt= /autoname;
run;

data returns_excl;
  if _n_=1 then set means_out(where=(_type_=0) rename=(return_mean=tot_return return_sumwgt=tot_wgts));
  set means_out(where=(_type_=1));
  return_excl = (tot_return*tot_wgts-return_mean*return_sumwgt)/(tot_wgts-return_sumwgt);
run;
```